# Django Simple History - is there any way to exclude the field "change reason" from the admin view of the historical records?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-simple-history

I am trying to exclude the field 'change reason' from the admin view of historical records, since I do not want the change reason field to be displayed on the table in the admin view

I tried adding:

`history = HistoricalRecords(excluded_fields='change_reason')`

still did not work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.